# why my logout function is not working in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the how form is submitted from view

```
<?php 

                        form_open('user/logout');
                        $data = array(
                            'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                            'name' => 'submit',
                            'value' => 'Logout'
                        );
                        echo form_submit($data);
                        form_close();

                        ?>
```

and in the controller method is

```
public function logout(){
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
                redirect('user/index');
            }
```

can anyone tell me what i have missed? Thank you

Comment: try to use ob_start and ob_clean. will work.

Comment: you'r session is working or not ?

Comment: Do you start a session? `session_start()` on top of the page

Comment: Check it please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423360/logout-in-codeigniter/18440885

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you have loaded session library in config file

Answer (score 0):

autoload['libraries'] = array('session');